Sum of independent Wisharts
Suppose random vectors $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m$ are independent and the distribution of each $y_i$ is a $d$-dimensional complex Gaussian with mean $0$ and covariance $\Gamma_i$, that is $y_i \sim \mathcal{CN}_d(0,\Gamma_i)$.
Let $Y := \begin{bmatrix}y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_m\end{bmatrix}$, that is the matrix whose columns are $y_i$s.
What do we know about the sum $W := YY^* =  y_1y_1^* + y_2y_2^* + \cdots + y_my_m^*$?
For example we can easily find the first three moments. The first moment is $\Sigma := \sum_i \Gamma_i$. With this notation, the second moment is $\Sigma^2 + \sum_i \operatorname{Tr}(\Gamma_i)\Gamma_i$.
Finally the third moment is $$\Sigma^3 + \sum_i \operatorname{Tr}(\Gamma_i)\Gamma_i \Sigma +\operatorname{Tr}(\Gamma_i)\Sigma \Gamma_i + \Gamma_i\operatorname{Tr}(\Gamma_i\Sigma)+\Gamma_i^3 + \Gamma_i\operatorname{Tr}(\Gamma_i)^2.$$
Can you obtain a closed form for every moment? What do we know about the distribution? Eigenvalue estimates?

We know that the distribution of $y_iy_i^*$ is the Wishart distribution with one degree of freedom, that is $y_iy_i^* \sim \mathcal{CW}_d(1,\Gamma_i)$.
The following paper gives the distribution of sum of two independent Wishart distribution $(m = 2)$ with arbitrary degrees of freedom and arbitrary covariance matrices:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6638
It gives the distribution function as well as eigenvalue statistics. The difference between what I am asking and the result of this paper is that for me $m$ is arbitrary but the degrees of freedom of each Wishart is one.
See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562600/sum-of-wishart-matrices.
